# Issue with Xmartlabs Eureka form builder on iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am having a bit of trouble with a part of the Eureka framework for Swift in iOS.  It works fine, except for when I try to clear out a form programatically which is already on the screen all the fields seem to clear out fine, except for the DecimalRow type field.

```
    (form.rowBy(tag: "name") as? TextRow)?.value = ""
    **(form.rowBy(tag: "amount") as? DecimalRow)?.value = Double(0.0)**
    (form.rowBy(tag: "date") as? DateRow)?.value = Date()
    (form.rowBy(tag: "reimb") as? SwitchRow)?.value = false
```

The DecimalRow type field stays whatever value was in it and does not respond to the line above in bold (asterisk-ed).

Any insight appreciated.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you reloaded the row?

This worked fine on my code.

```
    (self.form.rowBy(tag: "user_weight") as? DecimalRow)?.value = Double(0.0)
    (self.form.rowBy(tag: "user_weight")?.reload()
```

Where

```
<<< DecimalRow("user_weight")
```

And if I run
`self.form.values()` I get:

```
"user_weight": Optional(0.0)
```

So its cleared

You can also clear the form in this way

```
self.form.setValues(["user_weight": 0])
```

An example made by them

```
form.setValues(["IntRowTag": 8, "TextRowTag": "Hello world!", "PushRowTag": Company(name:"Xmartlabs")])
```

https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#how-to-set-the-form-values-using-a-dictionary

Comment: Thanks very much Pablo - that was in fact the issue, I was not reloading the form row in question...Many thanks!